# What module name do I use for drush dl?

Tags: 7, drush, files

I'm trying to install the Delete All module on Drupal 7 via Drush, but whenever I type `drush dl delete-all` I get the following error:

> No release history was found for the requested project (delete-all). [warning]

I thought it might have been related to case sensitivity, but trying other names like `Delete-All` and `DeleteAll` gave me the same error. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here, or is something wrong with my installation of Drush/Drupal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
drush dl delete_all
```

You have to check the project URL:

> [https://www.drupal.org/project/**delete_all**](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_all)

And use the last part, the project machine name.

The *delete-all* string is the drush command provided by this module.